# SSCLI (Rotor) for the v4.0 clr?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, clr, sscli

Does anyone know if there is (or will be) an SSCLI release for the v4.0 runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet, and there [doesn't look like there will be anytime soon.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/3cbb0121-295c-4b83-b4b1-afddf4ca5257)

> I get the information from the CLR
>   team that they are heads down
>   implementing somethings, and currently
>   have no plan to release SSCLI based on
>   .NET 4. They recommend that you use
>   SSCLI based on .NET 2 because it is
>   still a good reference for the ECMA
>   CLI.

Comment: Oh, right! There are other sites beside SO where people ask questions! Thanks for doing the leg work... have an upboat.

Comment: haha, thanks!  It's no problem, at least now SO has another question/answer pair to increase market share.  Sorry there's not a better answer for you though.